# Save Image in getter and setter and then in SQLite Database

Tags: android

I want to save the image in the getter setter and then in the Sqlite Database.Please Suggest any solution to store Bitmap image ?

Comment: Directly asking about the **CODE**...WOW !!!!

Comment: I select image from the Camera or Gallery and want that image to store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table like this tutoriel :

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

and for storing your image use the URI part of your file. (when you chose a picture from gallery or by taking photo you can get the Uri). After knowing the Uri you can put it in your database.

Say if it helps. If you have more questions, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

To save resource images into SQLite database:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
byte[] img = bos.toByteArray();

db = myDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("image", img);
db.insert(TABLE_IMAGE, null, cv);
```

For selecting the image from the Camera or Gallery then save to SQLite database, I would suggest saving the image's path only to save space.

Using these codes below, the images taken will also be saved to `My App's Images` in your Gallery so whenever you open your Gallery you can see which images were taken from within your app:

```
private static String imageFilePath;

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

// Choose picture from Gallery
Intent selectPictureIntent = Intent
                    .createChooser(intent, "Select Picture");
startActivityForResult(selectPictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);

// Take new picture
Intent captureImageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            // save selectedImagePath to your database
            finish();
    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            addImageToGallery(imageFilePath, context);
            // save imageFilePath to your database
            finish();
    }
}
```

Implement these methods:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else
        return uri.getPath();
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image*/
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}


/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "My App's Images");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("My App", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    imageFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(imageFilePath);
    return mediaFile;
}

public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath,
        final Context context) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), or search it on stackoverflow, this question has been asked several times.

Comment: i know but i cant find any solution.I am searching since morning.